# GWT. Exclude shared domain objects to separate Maven module

Tags: java, gwt, maven, multi-module

I have some Domain classes such as  `Student`, `User` etc which are used on server and client (gwt) sides.

Can I exclude this domain classes to separate *maven*-module, so I can add this module as dependency to other maven-modules (i.e. add this module as dependency to maven-module which contains gwt related stuff, so this domain classes will be generated to JavaScript, and add this module as dependency to "normal" (not gwt) Java maven-modules, so this domain classes  won’t be generated to JavaScript)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes sure, why not? Consider the following structure:

```
root-pom--->common
        |
        +-->frontend
        |
        +-->backend
```

Have `frontend` and `backend` depend on `common` and put your domain objects in `common`.

You should remember to have `*.gwt.xml` file exposing your VO's in the `common` project and include that in your `frontend`'s `gwt.xml` descriptor, eg.

```
<module>
    <source path="your.vo.package" />
</module>
```

And - as Thomas Broyer points out - remember to make the source code available to `frontend`, this does not necessarily have to be in a separate jar, though. You can package the source with the .class files. The `gwt-maven-plugin`'s `gwt:resources` goal is useful for this purpose:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Cheers,

Comment: Note you have to generate the -sources.jar for `common` and have `frontend` depend on both `common` "normal" and `common` -sources.jar. For an example of that, see https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes

Comment: thanks for reply. But I have a problem with this solution. I created new question. Please, view it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381493/gwt-maven-gwt-module-module-name-not-found-in-project-sources-or-resources