# GWT. Maven. GWT Module <module_name> not found in project sources or resources

Tags: gwt, maven, multi-project, gwt-maven-plugin

I have a maven multi-module project. One of this modules (compiled as `.jar`) contains only domain objects, which will be used at client and server sides (I add this `.jar` as dependency to other my modules).

I know that GWT module, where will be used objects from shared `.jar`, must also have source files for successful compilation. So I tried to add to my `pom.xml`  both:

```
        <resources> 
            <resource>
              <directory>src/main/java/<path></directory> 
              <includes> 
                <include>**/*.java</include> 
                <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include> 
              </includes> 
            </resource> 
        </resources>
```

and

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <versionRange>[${gwt.version}]</versionRange>
    <goals>
        <goal>resources</goal>
    </goals>
 <plugin>
```

But resulting `.jar` don't contain GWT module source (i.e `gwt.xml`). All sources of domain classes are added as well (at root directory of `.jar`), but `ModuleName.gwt.xml` not.

Where is problem? Thanks.

Comment: Where in the source tree is the gwt.xml file?

Comment: @MyTitle: as you're using GWT+Maven and building libraries, come cast your vote as the preferred/standard layout for GWT libraries (where to put `.gwt.xml` and the like): https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/Y0dqogsT1Zw/discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `.gwt.xml` file is in `src/main/resources/` then it won't get copied if you specify `src/main/java/` as the resource path...

You should probably omit the `<resource>` section and let the GWT plugin include the source in the jar or at least have two sections, one for the `.gwt.xml` file (`src/main/resources` or where you put it) and one for the source code (as you have it now).

Cheers,

Comment: In other words: if you have a `<resources>` section, it **replaces** the default `src/main/resources`, it doesn't **add** to it (the `<include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>` makes me wonder though if @MyTitle's `.gwt.xml` rather is in `src/main/java`).

Comment: My `.gwt.xml` in `ru.company.name.domain`, and my souce classes inside `ru.company.name.domain.object` package. Inside `src/main/resources` I haven't any files. And in `<resources>` section I tried also several variations of `.gwt.xml` path, e.g. `**/*.gwt.xml`, `*.gwt.xml` and also I tried full path etc (of course with a corresponding path changes in `<directory>` section).  **Anyway, why using `gwt-maven-plugin` results in same error?** (In question I meant that I tried both (`<resources>` and `gwt-maven-plugin` for generating sources) separately, but not together). Thanks.

Comment: Solved  using `<resources>` section (set correct path), but `gwt-maven-plugin` still doesn't work. This is strange..

Answer (score 0):

I was troubleshooting this error today so I'm just posting my fix:

Multi-module gwt project being build with the maven gwt plugin needs an entry in the pom.xml like:

```
  <modules>
        <module>../theothermodule</module>
  </modules>
```

In order to compile.

Answer (score 0):

This error have multiple explanations. Check list:

- if you are referencing a gwt module you need to point to the `*.gwt.xml` file in dot notation without the file extension. E.g. `com.example.ThirdParty` refers to `com/example/ThirdParty.gwt.xml` module
- to import the 3rd party module, add `<inherits name="com.example.ThirdParty" />` to your `*.gwt.xml` file
- the `ThirdParty.gwt.xml` should contain one or more `source` elements pointing to translatable code. E.g. `<source path='shared' />`.
- all translatable code in `ThirdParty.jar` needs to include plaintext `*.java` sources. E.g. `com/example/shared/Widget.class` and `com/example/shared/Widget.java` are both present
- the `ThirdParty.jar` is on your classpath

Notes:

- if the `ThirdParty` gwt module does not have entry point it does not need to be compiled with gwt compiler
- the gwt compiler does not require extra configuration to include the `ThirdParty` module as long as its jar is on classpath and your `*.gwt.xml` inherits `ThirdParty.gwt.xml`; the same applies to the gwt maven plugin